# Can Anybody explain how to convert .RDA file with four datasets to Excel file

Tags: r, export-to-excel

I am trying to see the file format and input data structure for DAPC analysis using Package "adegenet". As per the tutorial, the input file "dapcIllus" is the demo data and it is a list containing four datasets. I am a beginner in R, Can somebody explain how to convert this file to .xlsx with all four datasets, and also how to prepare such files with multiple datasets.

Link of "dapcIllus" dataset:
https://github.com/thibautjombart/adegenet/blob/master/data/dapcIllus.rda

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the file, try the following.

```
load("dapcIllus.rda")

data_list <- lapply(seq_along(dapcIllus), \(i) attributes(dapcIllus[[i]])$tab)
names(data_list) <- names(lengths(dapcIllus))
data_list <- lapply(data_list, as.data.frame)
writexl::write_xlsx(data_list, "dapcIllus.xlsx")
```